# How to delete lines in ivy-occur-mode?

Tags: ivy, swiper

In a typical search and replace type workflow, I use `swiper` to search for all instances of an expression that I want to edit in a buffer. To work on the instances collectively, I enter the `ivy-occur` edit mode.

The occur instances are displayed line by line. If I kill a line, it does not kill the newline character. How do I remove the newline character in the `ivy-occur` mode?